# cakephp form habtm jQuery autocomplete and add multiple

Tags: jquery, cakephp, autocomplete, addition, has-and-belongs-to-many

Calling all cakephp gurus.

Here is a tough one. I have a form that has a habtm relationship. Instead of adding hundreds of checkboxes in a form to select a customer or two an auto complete search on a habtm with a drop down of nearest to names with an add another button after selecting one from the auto complete would be heaven sent.

I have bought jquery books and have their code which has an example of the autocomplete search and another with the add another textfield as many times as you want but how to do this in cakephp 2.1 is so so so beyond me.

Is there anything similar out there that has been done in cakephp 2.1? I know its a biggy, but every project I seem to be doing requires this functionality in several areas.

It is a big problem that I think would help alot of cakephp developers out there.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Thanking you totally in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery select2 control at http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/. Use it to replace a select box that represents a habtm relationship on your form. It allows you to select multiple items easily and has the autocomplete search for which you are looking.